# Disable previous month link in Calendar control

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, calendar, web-controls

I am trying to find a way to disable the "Previous Month" link in my `Calendar` control. This seems like it should be a very simple task, yet I have not been able to find any properties or methods to do this, in the documentation.

Please note that I am looking for a way to disable *only the Previous Month* link, and not both links. Disabling just the "Next Month" link should be the same solution, so that would acceptable too. Please also note that the `ShowNextPrevMonth` property is an unfeasible solution, as it is used for hiding, which would be acceptable but less desirable, and hides both links, rather than just one.

[.NET Calendar Control Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Thanks for your help! Happy coding!

*Side-note: I am not looking for JavaScript solutions, as I can devise one fairly simply. However, if anyone does happen to know how I can apply a different `CssClass` to each of the links, I would up-vote that solution.*

Comment: I assume you mean an ASP.NET web control? (It would help if you could link to the exact control you're using, just to avoid any possibility of ambiguity.)

Comment: if "Next Month" link is enabled, do you want "Previous Month" link to be re-enabled when user moves to next month?

Comment: Sorry about that, @JonSkeet. I Have added the link, as requested :)

Comment: @Bolu - That is the plan, but I should be able to figure out how to do that, so long as I can figure out how to disable the "Next" link, initially. I would't turn down free information on how to re-enable it though ;)

Comment: I think you could handle the `OnVisibleMonthChanged` event? like do nothing if it moves to the previous month.. and here is an [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d04f55b2-3276-414e-8581-8892e9f19f6e/aspnet-calendar-disable-previous-month?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: @Bolu - I actually am handing the `OnVisibleMonthChanged` event. And it is pretty easy to throw a quick check in there to say "Nope - not happening - I'm not showing you the previous month." However, I still would prefer to be able to disable the button. I should note that JS solutions for this are not hard to create - I would just prefer to use a C#/.NET solution for this, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>ASP.NET Prevent Previous Month Selection - Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Calendar ID="someCalendar" runat="server"
     OnVisibleMonthChanged="theVisibleMonthChanged" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>




And the C# code for my demo is:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

/// <summary>
/// Demo to show how one might prevent the user from selecting 
/// the previous month in ASP.NET
/// 
/// References: 
/// [1] - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.visiblemonthchanged.aspx
/// [2] - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx
/// </summary>
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // How to attach visibleMonthChanged event is explained in [1]
        someCalendar.VisibleMonthChanged +=
            new MonthChangedEventHandler(this.theVisibleMonthChanged);
    }

    protected void theVisibleMonthChanged(Object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dateOfMonthToDisable = currentDate.AddMonths(-1);
        if (e.NewDate.Month == dateOfMonthToDisable.Month)
        {
            someCalendar.VisibleDate = e.PreviousDate;
            // Custom date formats are explained in [2] 
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
                this.GetType(), 
                "someScriptKey",
                "<script>" + 
                "alert(\"Can not go before today's month of " +
                currentDate.ToString("MMM-yyyy") +
                ".\");" + 
                "</script>"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution alerts the visitor that clicking the next/previous link would show a disabled month, which is not the same as hiding one link or the other.